# QNetworkAccessManager not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

This is a legacy code which I want to convert from Qt4 to Qt5.5.I don't know much about what happening on the server side.

I'm trying to convert following peace of code from Qt4 using QHttp to Qt5.5 using QNetworkAccessManager,

```
void JobCreator::CreateJob(QString userName, QString password, QString jobName, QString jobData)
{
    methodName = createJob;

    QHttpRequestHeader header = initialize();
    QString queryString = "function=CreateJob&username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&jobname=" + jobName + "&jobdata=" + jobData;
    httpRequestId = http->request(header, queryString.toUtf8());
}
```

I've changed this to following,

```
void JobCreator::CreateJob(QString userName, QString password, QString jobName, QString jobData)
{   
    methodName = createJob;

    QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("http");
    url.setHost("112.165.1.190");
    url.setPath("/BSR/job/");

    QByteArray qData;
    qData.append("function=CreateJob&");
    qData.append("username=" + userName);
    qData.append("&password=" + password);
    qData.append("&jobname=" + jobName);
    qData.append("&jobdata=" + jobData);


    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setUrl(url);

    reply = http->post(request, qData);
}
```

This code doesn't work. It gives 'Error: Connection Refused'. 
How do I convert this code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. Forgot to set port.

```
url.setPort(portNo)
```

and code works now.